# Getting string index out of range? python 3

Tags: python-3.x, uppercase, lowercase

My program is supposed to take an input in form of a string and split into to strings, one with all the lower case letters, underscores and dots. The other one with all the upper cases, the pipes and the spaces. I am not supposed to use (for function)

```
def split_rec (letters):
    uppers = ""
    lowers = ""
    if letters[0].isupper() or letters[0] == "|" or letters[0].isspace():
        uppers += letters[0] + split_rec (letters[1:])
    elif letters[0].islower() or letters[0] == "_" or letters[0] == ".":
        lowers += letters[0] + split_rec (letters[1:])
    elif not letters:
        return lowers, uppers
```

Can you please tell me more about the error I'm getting?

> if letters[0].isupper() or letters[0] == "|" or letters[0].isspace():
>   IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Because `letters` is the empty string?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my input would be letters = "HfEFfefF _"  e.g.

Comment: but you perform a recursive call on the tail of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a **recursive function**: the `split_rec` calls `split_rec (letters[1:])`. Since a string has finite length, eventually you will **pass it the empty string**. So that means that you can not access the first character, since it has no first character.

You can solve that problem by using a guard:

```
def split_rec (letters):
    uppers = ""
    lowers = ""
    if not letters:
        return lowers, uppers
    if letters[0].isupper() or letters[0] == "|" or letters[0].isspace():
        uppers += letters[0] + split_rec (letters[1:])
    elif letters[0].islower() or letters[0] == "_" or letters[0] == ".":
        lowers += letters[0] + split_rec (letters[1:])
    elif not letters:
        return lowers, uppers
```

But this will **not solve the problem**: since `split_rec` returns a tuple of two strings, you can not add this to a character. You can solve the problem by using:

```
def split_rec (letters):
    if not letters:
        return lowers, uppers
    lowers, uppers = split_rec(letters[1:])
    if letters[0].isupper() or letters[0] == "|" or letters[0].isspace():
        uppers = letters[0] + uppers
    elif letters[0].islower() or letters[0] == "_" or letters[0] == ".":
        lowers = letters[0] + lowers
    return lowers, uppers
```

But nevertheless **recursion that scales linear with input is in Python a bad idea**: Python does not optimize recursive calls, and so one easily gets a *StackOverflow exception* (this has nothing to do with this site).

You better use a generator and `join` the strings together:

```
def split_rec (letters):
    uppers = ''.join(c for c in letters if c.isupper() or c == "|" or c.isspace())
    lowers = ''.join(c for c in letters if c.islower() or c == "_" or c == ".")
    return lowers, uppers
```

Comment: >     lowers, uppers = split_rec()
TypeError: split_rec() missing 1 required positional argument: 'letters'

Thanks a lot, I understand what you did there but I'm getting this error now, I know i'm asking alot but I'm really learning of you

Comment: @nazeeroobu: yeah, I forgot to add the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

as @willemVanOnsem pointed out, you are recursively calling this on the string minus the first char. Eventually, you are calling it on an empty string, which is why you get an index error. check that "letters" is not empty before doing anything else.

as a side note, I don't think your recursive call is going to do what you expect.

can you use a while loop? you mention not using a for loop? or do you have to use recursion?